# programming statelistdrawable not working in dialog fragment

Tags: android-dialogfragment, statelistdrawable

I have an custom button, the state will changed when pressed to count down. I want to add the background under state. Here is my Java code:

```
    RoundedColorDrawable bg_enable = new RoundedColorDrawable(0, 0xffe8b655);
    bg_enable.setRadii(new float[]{0, 0, r, r, r, r, 0, 0});
    bg_enable.setBorder(0xffe8b655, bw);

    RoundedColorDrawable bg_disable = new RoundedColorDrawable(0, 0xffbcbcbc);
    bg_disable.setRadii(new float[]{0, 0, r, r, r, r, 0, 0});
    bg_disable.setBorder(0xffbcbcbc, bw);

    StateListDrawable bg_btn = new StateListDrawable();
    bg_btn.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.enabled}, bg_enable);
    bg_btn.addState(new int[]{}, bg_disable);
    ViewUtils.setBackground(mBtnCode, bg_btn);
```

But the background is always bg_disable, the button is in android DialogFragment. I don't known why the enabled state not working.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, it's my typing issue.

it's `android.R.attr.state_enabled` not `android.R.attr.enabled`